# Does grails/SQL automatically know which indices to use?

Tags: sql, grails, indexing, grails-orm

I have a simple domain class with two properties.  For example:

```
class Person {
  String firstName
  String lastName
}
```

Now I want to use the dynamic finders to find a guy named "Some Guy":

```
def thisGuy = Person.findByFirstNameAndLastName("Some","Guy")
```

What should I add to my person class to create the right indices in the database to make this search go quickly?  This is my current guess:

```
static mapping = {

    firstName index: 'Name_Idx'
    lastName  index: 'Name_Idx'
}
```

Is that correct, or should I make an index for each?

```
static mapping = {
    firstName index: 'Fname_Idx'
    lastName index: 'Lname_Idx'
}
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you on?  Some implementations will AND/OR the index, so you could use of each of the columns (the system controls this).  Otherwise, you may want one with both columns, in _each_ direction (depending on usage patterns).  Can't help you with the Grails bit.  But what happens to your database if you run it (assuming it creates some statement database side) - that should provide an easy way to check.

Comment: On MySQL for the moment.  Looks like having a multi-column-index will do better than multiple indices for this type of search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use:

```
static mapping = {
        firstName index: 'name_idx'
        lastName index: 'name_idx'
        description index: 'name_idx'
}
```

this will create 3 columns in the index **name_idx**.

Remember the columns will be listed in alphabetical order.

If you mean, "what is best: multiple indexes or multi-column indexes?" Well, it depends a lot. But, all in all, [this post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/22/multiple-column-index-vs-multiple-indexes/) will put you in the right path. The answer you are looking for is that it depends on the where clauses of your most used queries and your grouping.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question

Comment: "Is that correct, or should I make an index for each?" Well, it's correct.